# How do I show a 0 instead of this error #DIV/0! in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How do I use this formula

```
=SUM(B5-B4)/B3
```

and show a 0 instead of this error

```
#DIV/0!
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `IFERROR` function.

In your case it will be `=IFERROR(SUM(B5-B4)/B3, 0)`